# webbrowser control and memory problems

Tags: memory-management, webbrowser-control

My app is using roughly 300mb. I checked all objects i created with new and wrote a using around it if it had a dispose interface. Now with the web browser control i visit rougly 450 pages all which have ads on them and many use ajax request so for sure more then 1k request.

Why is the app taking that much memory? i did notice i can click the page and hit back to visit a previous page but AFAIK IE wouldnt use up that many MBs after visiting that many pages (i dont want to hit 450 unique pages by hand to check). So why do i have these memory issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which IE version are you using? The problem you describe is typical to IE5 and IE6 to a lesser degree.

I remember the days when we had to recycle an IE5 WebBrowser object because of memory leaks.
I'm not sure, but I believe the situation should be better with current generation IE.